# UIView touchesMoved not called if first finger released

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, touchesmoved

I want to achieve a simple task - detect up to 10 touches in a UIView.

Using these:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

It all works great.

**Problem is - `touchesMoved::` is no more called - if first finger, that touched screen no longer touches screen.**

Is it possible to fix it? (so that - while atleast one finger from 10 fingers is still touching screen - `touchesMoved::` would be called?

If it is not possible in UIKit, could it be possible in Cocos2d, and how? (some links, function peaces would be really helpful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just need to set `theView.multipleTouchEnabled`.